# onClick get GPS location

Tags: android

I want to get current GPS location when button is clicked. I have written this code (given below) but this gives `NullPointerException` for location object that is `Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`. please tell what is problem with my code?

**Code:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    }
    String cur_loc = "latitude = " + location.getLatitude() + "\n" + location.getLongitude(); //this is line 54 in my code
    Toast.makeText(ctx, cur_loc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Check the following, have you instantiate the findviewbyid for the button onclick, do you have the said button in the xml file, have you placed an onclicklistener?

Comment: make sure your registered button matches with the id of onClick or Add the code of class.

Answer (score 0):

`getLastKnownLocation (String provider)` may well return null. see [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)) :

> Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location
>   fix obtained from the given provider.
>
> This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this
>   location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned
>   off and moved to another location.
>
> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

try this method:

```
    private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
    Location bestLocation = null;
    for (String provider : providers) {
        Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (l == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
            // Found best last known location: %s", l);
            bestLocation = l;
        }
    }
    return bestLocation;
}
```

Now use it as:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location myLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
```